# How to manage notifications from other apps in Windows

Tags: c#, android, .net, winforms, notifications

I know Windows has its own [notification manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationmanager.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), but as far as I can tell, you can only access notifications your app has issued.

Is there any way to access notifications of other programs? I am looking for a similar functionality as the one offered by Android's [notification manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html). More specifically, I want to get the details of each notification as soon as it is posted/scheduled, for use in a different part of the program. Said details would be its title, any content text, possible images, an id/tag of sorts, etc.

I am working on a computer running Windows 10 Pro, with Visual Studio 2015 Community. My project is a WPF Application, and I am looking to hopefully get any `ToastNotification` regardless of which application it was posted by.

On Android, this matter seems trivial, as a simple "how to programatically access notifications in android" got me to an answer in as little as two clicks. However, for Windows, all the results I am getting are about creating and removing **your** notifications, about Android, or about JavaScript. And it is getting frustrating.

Comment: Your question is very broad and would be very diffiicult to answer. You need to do some more research, perhaps using your favourite search engine? Here's some help on how to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @GeoffJames Why does your comment make me feel like it is automated? Either way, I edited my question, It is broad, I have no doubt, because I am fairly new with .NET and C#.

Comment: No, it's completely human! :) - I understand you are new with .NET and C#. Everybody has to start somewhere - I was a beginner once, too. I think you need to do a lot more research before asking such a broad question. You need to include a bit more detail in your OP. Things such as which platform/GUI framework/.NET framework you're using. Here's a *very* handy blog post from Jon Skeet on things to consider *before* asking an SO question: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: Edited once again, I'm waiting for at least a clue.